# How to fix errors in Gridsome.js?

Tags: npm-install, yarnpkg, gridsome

I'm trying to launch a new [Gridsome](https://gridsome.org) project for local development. I've toyed with Gridsome in the past and had a great experience, so I decided to give it another shot.

This time around; however, when I run the `gridsome create` command, the system creates a new Gridsome site directory as expected but returns the following error message:

[image: First Gridsome error message after running the gridsome create command]

The instructions in this error message say to enter the newly-created site directory and run `gridsome develop` to start local development. However, after running `cd my-gridsome-site` and subsequently running `gridsome develop`, I then receive this error:

[image: Second Gridsome error message after entering new site directory and running the gridsome develop command]

So far, I've tried running `npm install --save` from the site directory as well as `yarn install`, both to no avail. Thinking that this was possibly tied to my terminal, I switched from using the Zsh terminal to using the Bash terminal. This also did not work.

I'm at a loss here and could really use a hand.

Comment: Images you posted not loading. can you paste the error message?

Comment: @AliSeivani the images are still loading on my end. Are they still not viewable for you?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please copy-paste the text so it's readable, copy-pastable and accessible.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an environment error. Gridsome requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) (v8.3+) and recommends [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/).

Make sure your Node.js version is `v8.3+` and use only one package manager like Yarn.

to check node version: `node -v`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, but I resolved it after installing yarn and running the project with yarn instead of NPM. So you should try using yarn it will help,